# Can I set up WhatsApp on my desktop when my smartphone is broken?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, android, whatsapp

I've been using WhatsApp on my Android Smartphone.
That phone is now broken, and until I have a new phone capable of running the WhatsApp App, I'm now using my older "non-smart" phone. My SIM card works well with it, but I can only do phone calls and SMS.

I have a couple of desktop/laptop PCs available, running Windows 7, 10, and Ubuntu.
So what exactly are the steps - installation(s) of additional software, use of a WhatsApp service for this kind of matters, ... to be able to have my WhatsApp account work with a "PC interface"? I can have my phone turned on at any time, but it is really old. No Android, no WhatsApp App.

Note that before I've been using WhatsApp Web from time to time, which needs the smartphone to be powered on and online, which I currently can't do. I can currently only use plain old mobile services with my mobile number: calls and SMS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an emulator like [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/) or [Remix launcher](http://www.jide.com/remixos).

Just install WhatsApp and manually input the confirmation code that you get through SMS make sure the phone number you use is the same as your  sim cards phone number.

Edit: this should work if you can still send/receive SMS as you only need to input the correct confirmation code that you get from an SMS message

Edit edit: an (almost) complete guide is at  WhatsApp: Getting started, it states: "Enter the number the same as you would if you were to make a phone call to that person." You should get an SMS from WhatsApp a few seconds after proceeding with the "confirmation code"
Which you will have to fill in the emulator"

Comment: Downvoter, does this not work? (It seems WhatsApp web [needs a smart phone](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87858/whatsapp-web-phone-not-connected), so an emulator might do the trick, but I don't know.)

Comment: >confirmation code that you get through SMS but I don't know.) – Arjan 5 mins ago
     
 
Than

Comment: Please, how can I edit my comments. It's impossible to a line breaks or am I missing something?

Comment: OK I try again: I don't know how to have Whatsapp send me anything via SMS. I don't remember that I did anything like that when initially installing Whatsapp on the (now no longer working) smart phone. Plus, how would Whatsapp know my actuall mobile phone number when the Whatsapp App runs inside an emulator? (I've never used one before)